# Yii2 необходимо создать дополнительную страницу для всего контента кроме главной site/index-content

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток! Уважаемые гуру, подскажите, как в Yii2 создать страницу site/index-content, что бы она была для всего контента кроме главной страницы. Поясню для чего: есть главная страница на ней одна шапка, а для других нужна другая шапка, в тоже время меню должно быть одно для всех. У меня расположение дефолтной страницы в page/index и как я понимаю мне нужна еще одна страница там же page/index-content к примеру. Варианты с $_SERVER не подойдут, нужно как я понимаю через URL Manager или что такое, средствами PHP. Возможно есть решение проще, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Решение - используйте layout

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade спасибо, что то я углубился, а это же проще! Спасибо, попробую, чуть позже отпишусь.

Comment: создай два layout. Одну для главной, другую - общую. И валяй)

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade спасибо Вам за наводку! Все сделал.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)